# How to apply bearer token to an odata source for a Devextreme dxdata grid

Tags: angular, typescript, devextreme, devextreme-angular

using angular and am trying to pass in a bearer token using an odata source with a devextreme dxdatagrid and I can't get it to authenticate and pull data, keeps returning "Current user did not login to the application!", indicating it's not authenticating.

I can successfully emulate the call using postman. DataSource definition below:

```
constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router
) {
    super(injector);
    let authString = "Bearer " + getToken();

    this.gridDataSource = {
        store: {
            type: 'odata',
            key: 'Id',
            keyType: "Int32",
            version: 4,
            url: 'http://localhost:21021/odata/Roles'
        },
        select: [
            'Id',
            'Name',
            'DisplayName'
        ],
        beforeSend: (e) => {  
            e.headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": authString
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Postman request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neGui.jpg)

I'm assuming I have the beforesend header definition incorrectly formatted, any help much appreciated

[xhr screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68L8f.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your browser's xhr request screenshot for this post request?

Comment: xhr screenshoot added

Answer (score 1):

The beforeSend function has to be inside the store object.

```
    this.dataSource = {
      store: {
        type: 'odata',
        key: 'Id',
        url: 'https://localhost:44350/odata/Books',
        version: 4,
        withCredentials: true,
        beforeSend: (e) => {
          e.headers = {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${jwtToken}`
          };
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **encoding** with **btoa**

```
let authString = "Bearer " + window.btoa(getToken()+ ':');
```

Comment: using window.btoa didn't seem to help, any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by defining the datasource as follows:

this.gridDataSource = new DataSource({
            store: new ODataStore({
                url: "http://localhost:21021/odata/Roles",
                key: "Id",
                keyType: "Int32",
                version: 4,
                beforeSend: (e) => {
                    e.headers = {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + abp.auth.getToken(),
                    };
                }
            })
         })